# launching R in AWS EC2

Tags: r, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to launch an R instance in AWS EC2. I have opted for the free tier and use the Amazon Linux AMI. In user data I have specified in the following manner to install R and Rstudio:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # install R
    yum install -y R
    # install RStudio-Server
    wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos6/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.5033- 
    x86_64.rpm
    yum install -y --nogpgcheck rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.5033-x86_64.rpm
    yum install -y curl-devel
    yum install -y openssl openssl-devel
    # add user
    useradd forecasting
    echo forecasting:testing | chpasswd
```

However, the R version is not the latest one - how do I **modify this code** to download the latest version of R?

Comment: Take a look at the instructions here on how to install a specific R version: https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/

Answer (score 0):

Using the instructions in this [installing R for RStudio link](https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/), I think the following might work for Centos 6. Unfortunately I can't check it, but it might give you something to work from.

```
#!/bin/bash
# install R runtime dependencies
yum install epel-release
# set R version
R_VERSION=3.6.2
# download and install R
wget https://cdn.rstudio.com/r/centos-6/pkgs/R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm
yum install -y R-${R_VERSION}-1-1.x86_64.rpm
# install RStudio-Server
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/centos6/x86_64/rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.5033- 
x86_64.rpm
yum install -y --nogpgcheck rstudio-server-rhel-1.2.5033-x86_64.rpm
yum install -y curl-devel
yum install -y openssl openssl-devel
# add user
useradd forecasting
echo forecasting:testing | chpasswd
```